# Capturing keyboard events for a limited time

Tags: javascript, programming-practices, event-programming, asynchronous-programming, typescript

I'm trying to code a kind of simple video game where there are two kind of players:

- **Human Players:** They enter an keyboard input
- **CPU Players:** A random input is calculated

For **Human Players** there is a `T` round time and a `T'` input entering time. Let's say, if `T=20` and `T'=5`, a player has 20 seconds to start typing, but only 5 seconds of typing time. So, if the player starts typing at `T=10`, will only be able to type those `T'=5` seconds until `T=15`.

Just so you know, I'm using Typescript, and I had something like this in mind:

```
while (!gameOver) {
   // do some stuff like knowing who's player turn is it

   var enteredInput;

   if (player.isHuman()) {
      enteredInput = captureKeyboardInputsFor(seconds);
   } else {
      enteredInput = calculateRandomCPUPlayerInput();
   }

   // process input & do actions
}
```

What I would like to achieve here is a kind of synchronous typing process, I have the game logic well defined in mind, but I'm trying to figure out how can I do this keeping my loop game synchronous (as the players play in turns), using TypeScript.

I would really appreciate any kind of guidance, alternatives or ideas of possible ways of solving my concerns.

Comment: You are going to have to rethink your approach to be more event driven.  JS is single-threaded.  While that `while` loop is running, keystrokes won't be registered and events won't fire.

Comment: @JohnWu you are totally right! But in this case this is just a very concrete scenario I have to get through and I have to try to do it "synchronously". I found an approximation that will do the trick: instead of having a loop, I will use recursion to achieve a synchronous flow. 
Thanks for your point, anyway!

Comment: At this point I am not sure what your question is, specifically.

Comment: I wanted `enteredInput = captureKeyboardInputsFor(seconds);` to be blocking, because players play in turns, so if it's let's say PlayerA's turn, PlayerB can't enter anything until his turn comes.

Comment: I just told you it's not possible.  You can't have code that is blocking and keyboard entry at the same time.

Comment: I've already implemented part of it.

Comment: If you wish to see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42705957/3023947

Comment: That is completely different from the example you provided in this post, and does not contain any functions that block while reading keyboard input.  Maybe you should start your question over without the oversimplified code example, which, again, can never work.

Comment: The oversimplified code was there with the purpose of letting the people know the kind of behavior I wanted to accomplish. Of course it was not the actual code.

Comment: You don't need to explain yourself to me.  If you'd like an answer you should start a new question showing the actual, asynchronous code structure you are using.  The difference between your example and your actual code are highly impactful to the answer.

Comment: When I first posted this, that actual code didn't exist.